# Можно ли в приложении Проект Win32 на Visual C++ использовать ini-файлы?

Tags: winapi, configuration, visual-c++, ini

Можно ли в приложении Проект Win32 на Visual C++ использовать ini-файлы, так как их используют в приложениях MFC? Например, что бы пользователь мог, перед запуском приложения, задать какие-то начальные настройки - скажем, начальные координаты геометрий Direct2D в окне приложения. В качестве среды разработки использую MS VS 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Используйте xml, оно намного лучше

Answer (score 1):

Гуглите по слову GetPrivateProfileString, но у нее ограничение на размер то ли файла, то ли секции есть.

Comment: Stack Overflow это место куда гугл может послать. Старайтесь давать более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: jfs, если возможно, то дайте, пожалуйста более подробную информацию о применении ini-файлов в приложении Win32. С благодарностью Евгений.

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? Указанная функция читает из INI файла значение в буфер в виде строки. Как этой информацией распоряжаться, когда читать, как называть секции и параметры и т.д. - решать исключительно автору программы.